# Is this a correct database design? (pk fk set and references)

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

So parents can have many clubs and children. 
Each clubs can have many teams that have children in them.
Children can join multiple teams.

I am confused with all these many relationships and I created a schema using a tool here: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5c455e3807ce540014df3eb2

Did I properly set keys and referenced them here?

Comment: is there any possibility that child might have child/children ?

Comment: And can 1 club has multiple parents?

Comment: club only has 1 parent as the owner

Answer (score 0):

your relational table design looks ok. Just as an alternative you may consider to use hierarchical table for parent and children. but, this is design consideration and it is totally up to you (follow YAGNI (you aren't gonna nead it) principles)

```
Table person {
  id int PK
  name varchar
  parent_id int
}

Table club {
  id int PK
  person_id int
  class_id int
  name varchar
}

Table team {
  id int PK
  club_id int
  children_id int
  num_of_children int
  name varchar
}


Ref: person.id < club.person_id
Ref: club.id < team.club_id
Ref: team.children_id < person.id
Ref: person.parent_id > person.id
```